# Using Dijkstra to find the shortest path for a robot that pickup objects

Tags: dijkstra, robotics

So basically, I have a warehouse represented by a graph and each node in it contains a certain amount of 3 objects (A, B, C). I have to use Dijkstra to find the shortest path the robot should take in order to take an amount of each item provided as the input and minimize the time.

[image]

Also, each time the robot picks an object, the robot's speed goes slower so the time it takes for him to travel a vertice isn't equal to its distance anymore. The given equation is **Time = Distance * k** where k is a constant associated with the robot (k= 1 + mass carried) and type A objects have a mass of 1kg, B objects of 3kg and C objects of 5kg.

My question is how can I modify or use the Dijkstra's algorithm given that I have to take into account the objects that I have to pick and the decrease of speed.

Answer (score 1):

When calculating the cost to go to a node, have another variable to account for time such that more items result in a larger number meaning more costly. So the total cost to go to a node is the sum of the cost between nodes and the variable accounting for time. The rest of Dijkstra should still work.